# Xpath is correct still getting: "Unable to locate element" error in WebDriver Sampler

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

This is the WebDriver Sampler code

```
    var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); //WebDriver classes
    var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get(url) //url from csv file
java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000)

var email = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//input[@id='j_username']"))
email.sendKeys("P1000003")
var pass = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//input[@id='j_password']"))
pass.sendKeys("Start123!")
pass.sendKeys(pkg.Keys.ENTER)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

This is the HTML snippet from where I'm getting xpath

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="fn-input__text-field ids-input ids-input--text ids-input--clear js-has-input-clear js-login-toggle-active-input-user" id="j_username" name="j_username" placeholder="E-Mail or User Name" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your fields located inside iframe? if yes, you should switch to frame to reach them, and after processing them switch to default to go back